# Adding View to GridLayout dynamically showing blank

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

It was working for a while and then suddenly stopped working.
I don't understand what exactly it is that i have changed in the code.
I am using volley to send a json array request which returns id, name, icon(url of the image).
I have checked and the data is coming from the server.

```
public void setup(JSONArray response) {

    ImageLoader imageLoader = VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).getImageLoader();

    gridLayout.removeAllViews();

    int total = response.length();
    int column = 3;
    int row = total / column;
    gridLayout.setColumnCount(column);
    gridLayout.setRowCount(row + 1);
    for (int i = 0, c = 0, r = 0; i < total; i++, c++) {
        if (c == column) {
            c = 0;
            r++;
        }
        final float scale = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int pixels = (int) (90 * scale + 0.5f);
        Log.e("TAG", "pixels: " + pixels);

        GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        param.height = pixels;
        param.width = pixels;
        param.rightMargin = 5;
        param.leftMargin = 5;
        param.bottomMargin = 5;
        param.topMargin = 5;
        param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(c);
        param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(r);

        try {
            jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
            final String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
            final String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
            final String icon = jsonObject.getString("icon");

            LinearLayout llParent = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            linearLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            llParent.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);
            llParent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            NetworkImageView iv = new NetworkImageView(getActivity());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams ivLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(80, 80);
            ivLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            iv.setLayoutParams(ivLayoutParams);
            if (icon.length() > 0) {
                iv.setImageUrl(icon, imageLoader);
            } else {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
            }
            iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        callbacks.onFragmentInteraction(id, name);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.toString();
                    }

                }
            });

            TextView tv1 = new TextView(getActivity());
            tv1.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);
            tv1.setText(name.toUpperCase());
            tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
            tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
            tv1.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

            llParent.setLayoutParams(param);

            llParent.addView(iv);
            llParent.addView(tv1);

            gridLayout.addView(llParent);
            jsonObject = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

Comment: can you post logcat report, it would help

Comment: what can i log here ? the response from JSONArrayRequest ?

Comment: if the application stopped then it might be due to some exception or memory error...so if you can post the logcat report(i.e stacktrace) it might help to resolve the issue